# Converting html links to target in r

Tags: r, curl, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape data from ABS.gov.au using r but each of the links, instead of point to a file has this format:

```
http://abs.gov.au/ausstats/meisubs.NSF/log?openagent&640101.xls&6401.0&Time Series Spreadsheet&401EDAE91BAF3EB6CA2581680012D506&0&Jun 2017&26.07.2017&Latest
```

Is there anyway to download the file sitting behind the link above using r (potentially curl)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objective is to just download the file, this is how to do it.

```
url = "http://abs.gov.au/ausstats/meisubs.NSF/log?openagent&640101.xls&6401.0&Time Series Spreadsheet&401EDAE91BAF3EB6CA2581680012D506&0&Jun 2017&26.07.2017&Latest"
dest = 'downloaded_file.xls'

download.file(url,dest)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to read the file through readxl and my r session shuts down. Then I tried to open it in explorer and it came back as corrupted. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem could be because of the file format. Are you sure it's an excel file? I managed to download the same file as in the attachment and open it successfully.